# Obtain Polygon Extent with Multiple Polygons within Shapefile

Tags: python, shapely, extents, fiona

I have a shapefile that contains multiple polygons. I would like to extract the extent of each of those polygons within that shapefile. The majority of answers that I have been able to find use ArcPy and I do not have ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, [so I cannot use it](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/running-arcpy-without-having-arggis-pro-or-arcgis-desktop/m-p/880889#:%7E:text=With%20ArcMap%2C%20No.,on%20machines%20with%20neither%20installed.). So far I have code that will obtain the extent of the shapefile, but not each individual polygon within the shapefile. I am using `fiona` and `shapely`.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona

path = 'D:/data/shapefile/'
file = '__932.shp'

c = fiona.open(path + file)
field = next(iter(c)
extent = shape(field['geometry']).bounds
print(extent)

# (465452.3213890702, 4924992.33678632, 465453.50800855865, 4924993.2240787465)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many solutions

With fiona

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
layer = fiona.open("test.shp")
# now layer is a generator/iterator so you can use next()
shape(next(layer)['geometry']).bounds # gives the bound of the first feature
(204386.82131440676, 89543.4759701695, 204422.20968847454, 89578.86434423728)
shape(next(layer)['geometry']).bounds # gives the bound of the second feature
(204351.43294033897, 89508.0875961017, 204386.82131440676, 89543.47597016949)
.....
```

But it's easier with a for loop:

```
for geom in layer:
    print(shape(geom['geometry']).bounds)
(204386.82131440676, 89543.4759701695, 204422.20968847454, 89578.86434423728)
(204351.43294033897, 89508.0875961017, 204386.82131440676, 89543.47597016949)
(204386.82131440676, 89508.0875961017, 204422.20968847454, 89543.47597016949)
(204351.43294033897, 89472.69922203392, 204386.82131440676, 89508.0875961017)
```

With [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file("test.shp")
print(df.geometry.bounds)
        minx          miny           maxx          maxy
204386.821314  89543.475970  204422.209688  89578.864344
204351.432940  89508.087596  204386.821314  89543.475970
204386.821314  89508.087596  204422.209688  89543.475970
204351.432940  89472.699222  204386.821314  89508.087596

print(df.total_bounds) # bounds of the whole shapefile
[204351.43294034  89472.69922203 204422.20968847  89578.86434424]
```

With [PyShp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) (in pure Python)

```
import shapefile
reader = shapefile.Reader("test.shp")
for geom in reader.shapeRecords():
    print(shape(geom.shape.__geo_interface__).bounds)
(204386.82131440676, 89543.4759701695, 204422.20968847454, 89578.86434423728)
(204351.43294033897, 89508.0875961017, 204386.82131440676, 89543.47597016949)
(204386.82131440676, 89508.0875961017, 204422.20968847454, 89543.47597016949)
(204351.43294033897, 89472.69922203392, 204386.82131440676, 89508.0875961017)
```

Control with your solution

```
shapefile = ogr.Open("test.shp")
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    extent = geometry.GetEnvelope()
    print(extent)
(204386.82131440676, 204422.20968847454, 89543.4759701695, 89578.86434423728)
(204351.43294033897, 204386.82131440676, 89508.0875961017, 89543.47597016949)
(204386.82131440676, 204422.20968847454, 89508.0875961017, 89543.47597016949)
(204351.43294033897, 204386.82131440676, 89472.69922203392, 89508.0875961017)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from [Get feature extent using gdal/ogr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975952/get-feature-extent-using-gdal-ogr) at Stack Exchange using the `osgeo` library

```
from osgeo import ogr

path = 'D:/data/shapefile/'
file = '__932.shp'

shapefile = ogr.Open(path + file)
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    extent = geometry.GetEnvelope()
    print(extent)
```